# Rails rollback, change type and migrate again

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, rollback

I have a requests table;

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.string :from
      t.string :to

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to rollback the database with `rake db:rollback STEP = 5`
destroy the Request model and create request table with;

```
t.datetime :from
t.datetime :to
```

However, I have a migration table to Request model on STEP = 2,

```
class AddStatusToRequest < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :requests, :status, :string, :default => "Pending"
  end
end
```

The problem is, if I destroy Request table and create new Request table with datetime types it creates after STEP = 2 and when I `rake db:migrate` rails does not add Status column to Request table. How can I overcome this?

Comment: What happens if you run migrations from scratch? Do you get an error on the `AddStatusToRequest` migration because `requests` doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new migration to change the column type using `change_column`:

command line: `rails g migration change_request_to_from_column_types'`

new migration:

```
class ChangeRequestToFromColumnTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :requests, :from, :datetime
    change_column :requests, :to, :datetime
  end
end
```

Comment: I have used this method but is there another way?

Comment: If you are not operating on live data you could do something like `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=<version from step=5>` and repeat for file from step=2. But as Anthony E pointed out, it's generally better not to change existing migrations.

Answer (score 2):

It's best not to retroactively change migrations after they've been applied to avoid state conflicts like the one you have. Perhaps the simplest solution is to create a new migration to add the types to the `requests` table using a guard to do nothing if the column already exists:

```
class AddStatusToRequestIfNotExists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    unless column_exists? :requests, :status
      add_column :requests, :status, :string, :default => "Pending"
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

You'll also want to make sure that you can run migrations from scratch, so you might want to update your existing migration to guard against a missing table as follows:

```
class AddStatusToRequest < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    unless table_exists? :requests
      add_column :requests, :status, :string, :default => "Pending"
    end
  end
end
```

Not ideal, but it's probably the safest approach.